# How to edit list into dataframe and edit whole rows and columns

Tags: r, rvest

I'm using `rvest` to scrape a website, I generate this table:

```
        X1               X2         X3                  X4
1 <U+76EE>         <U+5B58>    <U+5B58>            <U+5468>
2 <U+76EE>       12<U+5468>  11<U+5468>    <U+589E><U+51CF>
3 <U+533A>            41.63        51.9               -10.3
4 <U+533A>             30.3          35               -4.7
```

Using `table_ <- html_nodes('table') %<% html_table(fill = TRUE)`

When I check the type of `table_` it says it's a `'list'` but it doesn't look like one...
I want either to edit this 'list' to look something like this:

```
        A               B          C                D
1 North               abc        def               ggg
2 South            week 12      week 11          change
3 East               41.63        51.9            -10.3
4 West                30.3          35             -4.7
```

Or delete rows `1`, `2` and column `X1`

Comment: Please make this example reproducible. Print methods in `rvest` may obscure the exact nature of the object. If you used `html_nodes` instead of `html_node`, it will return a `list` with one element corresponding to each matched node. If there's only one table, you can pipe to `[[(1L)` to unlist this.

Comment: I did use `nodes`, what does  "pipe to `[[(1L)` to unlist this" mean?

Comment: `... %>% html_nodes(...) %>% ... %>% html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% \`[[\`(1L)`

Comment: Ahh that got it into a table! how do I omit the first two rows, and the first column?

Comment: the same way you would for any `data.frame`...